# How to rollback in perforce(p4) to a changelist using a command line(Not Gui)

Tags: perforce

I am a perforce beginner user.
I am writing a script that adds, deletes and edits files and revert all changes at the end.

I tried to do the following to revert all changes:

p4 sync   @oldRevision

p4 add

p4 sync

p4 resolve -ay

p4 submit

and this revert all changes and add the deleted files but it does not remove the new added files.
How can I remove the new added file?

I noticed that when I run "p4 sync   @oldRevision" the new created file which was not exist in this release are mapped from the latest release and may be this is the issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p4 undo "@>oldRevision"
```

Or if `oldRevision` is a changelist, add 1 and use a range.  I.e. these two commands are the same:

```
p4 undo "@>1000"    # undo all changes after 1000
p4 undo @1001,@now  # undo all changes from 1001 to now
```

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_undo.html
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html#filespecs.synopsis.using_revision_ranges

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help
I tried to run with the following command: 
p4 -c p4Client undo -c changeLst dir_path_in_myworkspace/... @>oldchangelist

but I got error messages:
Usage: undo [ -n ] [ -c change ] file[revRange]
Missing/wrong number of arguments.

I tried to sync the directory first and open for edit but still does not work
is am running the command in correct way?
and should I sync the old revision first?

Comment: Don't have a space between the path and the rev specifier (it's all one thing; the rev specifier modifies the path).  Use `"double quotes"` if you're using the `@>` syntax or your shell will interpret the `>` as a redirect.  Don't open the files first.